# Variable scope inside loops in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, anonymous-function

I am trying to create interactive markers in Google maps. Here is the array to create the markers:

```
var markers = [
    {"id":17,"ti":"33 Star Hotel","lat":3.14648,"lng":101.711,"ty":5,"lid":"3","desc":""},
    {"id":9,"ti":"Aquaria KLCC","lat":3.15392,"lng":101.713,"ty":10,"lid":"3","desc":""},
    {"id":28,"ti":"Batu Ferringhi","lat":5.47436,"lng":100.247,"ty":15,"lid":"4","desc":""},
];
```

The markers are added to the map *n* if the markers location id *lid* is equal to n.

When a marker is clicked, I want the markers *array index* to be displayed, but they all show the final value of *i* (markers.length).

```
function map_center(n) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        if ( markers[i].lid == n ) {
            var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: markers[i].lat, lng: markers[i].lng },
                map: map,
                title: markers[i].ti,
                icon: icons[markers[i].ty],
            });
            m.addListener( "click", function(){
                alert("click:" + i );
            });
            markers[i].dom = m;
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow, the anonymous function needs a parameter to get a copy of the current value of *i*. I found this solution here on SO and it works, but i do not like passing parameters this way:

```
var m = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: markers[i].lat, lng: markers[i].lng },
    map: map,
    title: markers[i].ti,
    icon: icons[markers[i].ty],
    i: i
});
m.addListener( "click", function(){
    alert("click:" + this.i );
});
```

How should this be done properly?

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling! I did not know the fancy words _closure inside loops_! It was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything in an iife

```
function map_center(n) {
for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    (function(i) {
        if ( markers[i].lid == n ) {
            var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: markers[i].lat, lng: markers[i].lng },
                map: map,
                title: markers[i].ti,
                icon: icons[markers[i].ty],
            });
            m.addListener( "click", function(){
                alert("click:" + i );
            });
            markers[i].dom = m;
        }
    })(i)
}
```